# Its is Customer Care Data How to build query comparing text rows one by one to customer weather is satisfied or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have customer care data I need to check whether the customer is satisfied or not.
I have 4 columns id, Type, Title, date, customer id.
customer interaction always begins where [title] = 'Verification'.
For each customer interaction, when all records have [type] = 'Call' then 'successful'
For each interaction where the first record is [title] = 'Verification' AND any activity within the interaction has [type] <> 'Call' then 'unsuccessful' else Null
Sample data

```
|Id| |Type|   |Title|            |date|   |customer Id|
|22 Call    verification        22/05/2020    100
|26 Call    self inputs         22/05/2020    100
|34 Ticket  Waiting ticket      22/05/2020    100
|4  Call    verification        17/01/2020    105
|7  Call    information         17/01/2020    105
|9  call    issue               17/01/2020    105
|12 call    verification        17/01/2020    105
|56 Chat    support             11/03/2020    150
|64 Call    verification        11/03/2020    150
|72 call    inputs              11/03/2020    150
|84 call    information         11/03/2020    150
|86 call    verification        11/03/2020    150
|88 Support cancellation        11/03/2020    150
|90 call     verification       11/03/2020    150
|92 complain  Transferred       11/03/2020    150
```

If you look at the data **100 customer ID**
its unsuccessful all records doesn't have [type] = 'Call'

```
|Id||Type|    |Title|            |date|   |customer Id|
|22 Call    verification        22/05/2020    100
|26 Call    self inputs         22/05/2020    100
|34 Ticket  Waiting ticket      22/05/2020    100
```

For **105 customer ID** its successful
These customer interactions are made of 4 activities total
All records have [type] = 'Call'

```
|Id| |Type|   |Title|            |date|   |customer Id|
|4  Call    verification        17/01/2020    105
|7  Call    information         17/01/2020    105
|9  call    issue               17/01/2020    105
|12 call    verification        17/01/2020    105
```

For **150 customer ID** we have both successful and unsuccessful
These customer interactions are made of 8 activities total
In that there are 3 because there are 3 verification activities
The first customer interaction are only Call type, so these records should return 'successful'
For the 2nd customer interaction, it began with [type] = 'call' but has records where [type] <> 'call' these records should return 'unsuccessful'
For the 3rd customer interaction, it began with [type] = 'call' but has records where [type] <> 'call' these records should return 'unsuccessful'

```
|Id| |Type|   |Title|            |date|   |customer Id|
|56 Chat    support             11/03/2020    150
|64 Call    verification        11/03/2020    150
|72 call    inputs              11/03/2020    150
|84 call    information         11/03/2020    150
|86 call    verification        11/03/2020    150
|88 Support cancellation        11/03/2020    150
|90 call     verification       11/03/2020    150
|92 complain  Transferred       11/03/2020    150
```

Expected result

```
Id| Type   |Title              |date      |customer Id  |Expected Output
_______________________________________________________________________
22  Call    verification        22/05/2020    100       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
26  Call    self inputs         22/05/2020    100       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
34  Ticket  Waiting ticket      22/05/2020    100       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
4   Call    verification        17/01/2020    105       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
7   Call    information         17/01/2020    105       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
9   call    issue               17/01/2020    105       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
12  call    verification        17/01/2020    105       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
56  Chat    support             11/03/2020    150       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
64  Call    verification        11/03/2020    150       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
72  call    inputs              11/03/2020    150       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
84  call    information         11/03/2020    150       successful
_______________________________________________________________________
86  call    verification        11/03/2020    150       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
88  Support cancellation        11/03/2020    150       unsuccessful
______________________________________________________________________
90  call     verification       11/03/2020    150       unsuccessful
_______________________________________________________________________
92  complain  Transferred       11/03/2020    150       unsuccessful
```

I tried below code to achieve but not getting accepted result

```
`SELECT  id, type, title, date, Customer ID,`
`row_number () `
`over(PARTITION by Customer ID, date order by Customer ID, date, id) as rk`
`, NULL Callsuccess`
`into #temp` 
`FROM [dbo].[CallData]`

`select T1.id, T2.id  as id_2 `
`into #temp2`
`from #temp T1 `
`inner join #temp T2  on T1.CustomerID=T2.CustomerID` 
`and T1.date=T2.date` 
`and T1.rk=T2.rk-1`
`and T2.Type='Call'`
`and T1.Type='Call'`
`and T2.title<>'Verification'`

`update #temp  set Callsuccess='successful'  where id  in (select id  from #temp2)`

`update #temp  set Callsuccess='successful' where id  in (select id_2  from #temp2)`
```

Comment: Your question is unclear because it does not define "successful" and "unsuccessful".  You need to be clear on explaining that logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
here the logic is simple when ever the customer contact type= Call and he should do change this type to another type if he changed the type its unsuccessful if customer stays with type = Call for all records its successful

Comment: . . The logic may seem simple to you but the *question* does not clearly explain the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated the logic